# Update View from loop

Tags: ios, ipad, loops, user-interface

I have read several threads on this topic, but did not manage to find an answer yet.
In my iOS App, I am downloading data from a SOAP Webservice using the classes provided by sudzc.com. Then i save the data to a CoreData database. To do so, I have to loop through sets of data (for-loop). As there may be lots of data, I want to provide status updates to the UI.
The saving is managed by the WebServiceHelper class which defines a delegate to push status information to the view controller. The delegate is set correctly as some of the messages are beeing displayed, but I did not manage to update the view from inside a loop or call the delegate twice in one long running method.
I tried `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` but that did not change anything.
Is there any other way to force the UI to update?

Comment: UI changes need to go on the main thread, and your long-running operation should be on a background thread. To dispatch UI updates from the background, you can do something like `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{ // update UI here }];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI changes need to go on the main thread, and your long-running operation should be on a background thread.

Assuming your loop is running in a background thread, you can trigger UI updates by do something like this:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // update UI here
}];
```

This will execute the block on the main runloop. An alternative is to use the GCD APIs, but I like to stay at the Obj-C/Foundation level if possible.